# How to get the user running most number of processes in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so I used {ps -eo user|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -1} to get the user with most number of processes. However, I get sth like 946 root, but I only want to display the user name and not the number of processes. That is I only want to display root. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

`ps -eo user|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -1|awk '{print $2}'`